# Internal CNAME record to Azure App Service fails

Tags: azure, web-applications, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

I have an Azure web app. Let's call it contoso.azurewebsites.net.
To make it easier for internal users to connect, I create a CNAME record in our internal DNS. This record is called contoso.corp.net and points to contoso.azurewebsites.net.

Now, when I open contoso.corp.net from the internal website, the name is resolved. It is then redirected to an address ending with .cloudapp.net but the page is not displayed correctly.

Is this scenario supported?

Comment: Is the issue about the redirection happening/not happening? Or is it about the website showing some error like 404 or something. Your question is not clear. Also, the azure domain is .azurewebsites.net, and then your domain .corp.net...and then you also have cloudapp.net? Its too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently App Services only support public DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so Azure only supports to respond to public DNS records.

For now, I created an internal website with a redirection.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this scenario supported?

No, this is not supported for internal DNS. To make a custom domain work, we also need to add the host name to Azure Web App custom domains using Azure portal.

[image]

In addition, Azure Web App will validate the host name availability and domain ownership. If either of these failed. The adding hostname act is failing. Since your custom domain is setting in your internal DNS. It will not pass the domain validation.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not supported, you can request this feature in uservoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites